# Ajax Jquery Check the input is valid php

Tags: php, jquery, function, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have bootstrap form that checks the validation input.
Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

http://pastebin.com/C3BZ8Arj

I want it to look like :http://alittlecode.com/jquery-form-validation-with-styles-from-twitter-bootstrap/

Comment: While pastebin is handy, you do need to post some coding examples and what you're expecting. Consider improving your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just the validaton for the `$url` and `$email` :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jsValidateSubdomain').validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },
      url: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      }
    },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
  });

});
```